# Good example showing why limits must exist in limit product rule

Tags: limits, education, examples-counterexamples, products

I'm looking for a way to show my calc 1 students not to use the limit laws without knowing that the individual limits exists. I could use $$\lim_{x\to 0} x^{2} \sin(1/x),$$

but by doing it wrong, one still gets the right answer, which is 0. So I'm looking for an example where splitting up the limit would actually give the wrong answer. I think $\lim_{x\to 0} x \csc(1/x)$ ought to work, but I'd like an even simpler example, if possible.

Comment: Should it also give an answer at all? In your case splitting the limits gives no actual answer, when you write it out correctly.

Comment: User that sin is limited.

Comment: @Ian is correct. $\sin(1/x)$ is undefined as $x \to 0$. $0 \times$ undefined is not zero.

Comment: I know that, but students just think that because 0 times anything is 0 the answer is 0. And they happen to be right. @trb456

Comment: @QuinnCulver: No, they do **not** happen to be right. Zero times undefined is **not** zero. If your students believe that zero times anything is zero then they have been badly misinformed. You should correct their knowledge.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking: if $\lim_{x\to x_0} g(x)$ fails to have a limit, how could students get a numerical answer to $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) g(x)$ by splitting up the limit?  Are you looking for cases where they might mistakenly conclude that the whole limit does not exist?

Comment: $\lim_{x \to 0} x \cdot \frac{1}{x}$

Comment: Actually, @Hurkyl, that example I don't really want because I think students are less likely to think that 0 times $\infty$ is 0 (or $\infty$). Note that this example was suggested in one of the answers, too.

Comment: @trb456 please notice the ``they happen to be right'' remark by the OP is referring to the answer, i.e. they happen to be right the answer is $0$, not to the wrong belief that $0\,\times\,\text{(indeterminate)}=0$.

Answer (score 1):

One can say that for $x$ to +infinity on $y=\sqrt{x^2-4x}$ that $\sqrt{x^2-4x}=\sqrt{x^2(1-4/x^2)}=x\sqrt{1-4/x^2}=x$ because the square root term goes to 1. Therefore the slant asymptote is $y=x$ This is an example of the incorrect use of limit laws since the first term, $x$ has a limit that does not exist for $x$ to infinity. There is a slant asymptote for $x$ to infinity that has a slope of $1$ but also a nonzero $b$ value. I want YOU to figure that out since you are a Calc 1 teacher :)

Comment: I don't think this is the kind of example I'm looking for. Thanks though.

Comment: @QuinnCulver. It is an example that does fit in a rigorous  Calc 1 course. It does demonstrate the rule that the individual limits must exist in order for their product as a limit to exist. That is what you put in the first sentence of your post. I showed an incorrect use of that rule as $x$ goes to infinity. Now the only problem with my example is that Calc1 students may not have a good understanding of (calculating) slant asymptotes. In fact, my experience is that weaker students at the Calc1 level can't calculate slant asymptotes other than the ones that arise from long division.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is the kind of thing you are looking for:

Define the sequence $x_n=(-1)^n$.

"Therefore", we have that:

$1=\lim x_n^2"="(\lim x_n)^2.$

"So", $\lim x_n=1$ or $-1$.

Also, you could use $x$ and $\frac{1}{x}$ if they think that the argument "$0$.anything=$0$" is valid.

Comment: Thanks. These are both good ideas. As to the first, we're not talking about sequences in this class. I considered the second, but I think for most beginners it's clear that when you have a $0\cdot \infty$ product it's not obviously zero. I suppose they're more likely to use the "anything times zero is zero" argument in the $x^{2} \sin(1/x)$ case precisely because they don't know that $\sin(1/x) \to \infty$ as $x \to 0$ (which of course is false anyway). See what I mean?

Comment: @QuinnCulver: You're not really going to be able to avoid an $0\cdot \infty$ example, because if $f(x)$ goes to $0$ and $g(x)$ is bounded, then $f(x)g(x)$ goes to $0$ as well.  You could maybe try to make $g$ some complicated function that goes to $\infty$ but such that it is not obvious it does at a first glance, while $f$ goes to $0$, but $g$ is actually asymptotic to $1/f$ so the product goes to $1$.

Comment: @EricWofsey That's why I suggested $\csc(1/x)$, it doesn't go to $\infty$, but certainly has $\infty$ as its $\limsup$.

Comment: @QuinnCulver, I don't see what's wrong with $\lim_{x\to 0} x \csc(1/x)$ as an example.  If you want it to be "simpler" (i.e. understandable by more students), you could omit the `csc` and use $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac x {\sin(1/x)}$.